# Confusing result when using RedisTemplate to execute lua scripts

Tags: java, spring-boot, lua, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-redis 2.0.5.RELEASE. I execute a lua script with RestTemplate. 
The script:

```
-- hold.lua
if redis.call('get', KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then
    redis.call('pexpire', KEYS[1], ARGV[2])
    return 1
end
return 0
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
public void executeHold(String lockKey, String lockValue, long expireInMillis) {
    DefaultRedisScript<Boolean> holdScript = new DefaultRedisScript<>();
    holdScript.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("lua/hold.lua"));
    holdScript.setResultType(Boolean.class);
    // CODE 1
    Boolean result = redisTemplate.execute(holdScript, Collections.singletonList(lockKey), lockValue, expireInMillis);
    // END of CODE 1
    //        // CODE 2
    //        String script = holdScript.getScriptAsString();
    //        Boolean result = redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Boolean>() {
    //            @Override
    //            public Boolean doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
    //                return connection.scriptingCommands()
    //                        .eval(
    //                                script.getBytes(),
    //                                ReturnType.fromJavaType(Boolean.class),
    //                                1,
    //                                lockKey.getBytes(),
    //                                lockValue.getBytes(),
    //                                String.valueOf(expireInMillis).getBytes()
    //                        );
    //            }
    //        });
    //        // END of CODE 2
    System.out.println(holdScript.getSha1());
    LOGGER.debug("Execute holdScript, result={}, content=\n{}", result, holdScript.getScriptAsString());
}
```

I have set `lockKey` in redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set lockKey lockValue PX 600000 NX
```

When I run the code above, with `CODE 1` used, i always get `result = false`.

But when I change the code above, with `CODE 2` used, i can get correct result expectedly.

It really confused me, could anybody help me to find what's wrong with it? Thank you.

What i want to do is [Here](https://github.com/hatakawas/redlock-spring-boot-starter).

Comment: before setLocation, can you 'setScriptSource'? Seems like the script is not loaded

Comment: @wsha I read the source code, setLocation is the same as setScriptSource. i am sorry, i find the real reason, it's just caused by  the redisTemplate.execute() method, it looks like it always give me a wrong result, but i don't know why.....I've edited the question, can you try it again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. The root cause of my issue was that I was using json serializer in my redis template and it was adding extra quotes in the string values I was passing to the script. Changing the serializer to string serializer resolved my issue.